# Finding injection from $[0,1]$ to $P(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm using Schröder-Bernstein to prove that $\mathbb{R}$ is equinumerous to $P(\mathbb{N})$, the power set of the naturals. Part of my proof requires that I find an injection from $[0,1]$ (which is equinumerous with $\mathbb{R}$) to $P(\mathbb{N})$. I already found the reverse injection by encoding membership of $n$ as the $n$th bit in a binary sequence following the decimal point.

Hints appreciated!

**Edit**: Thanks for all the suggestions. For those interested, I concluded that the following would be the most accessible and elegant way for me to prove $[0,1]$ is equinumerous with $P(\mathbb{N})$.

Let $f: [0,1] \rightarrow P(\mathbb{N})$ be defined as follows. Each $c \in [0,1]$ can be written in binary uniquely as $a_1.a_2a_3...$ by choosing the canonical representation of nonterminating $0$s rather than nonterminating $1$s when there is a choice. Then $f(c) = \{k: a_k = 1\}$ gives an injection.

Let $g  : P(\mathbb{N})\rightarrow [0,1]$ work as follows. For any $A \in P(\mathbb{N})$, $g(A)$ is the *decimal, rather than binary,* representation $0.a_1a_2\ldots$, where for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $a_k = 1$ if $k \in A$ and $0$ otherwise. Note that we ensure injectivity because, in decimal, a number of the form $0.a_1a_2\ldots$ will only have multiple representations if one of them has a nonterminating tail of $9s$.

By Schröder-Bernstein, we have $\mathbb{R}$ is equinumerous to $P(\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: prove that function you mentioned is surjection as well

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/56633/simple-bijection-between-reals-and-sets-of-natural-numbers

Comment: @user26977 I think that it is usually easier to utilize http://www.cut-the-knot.org/WhatIs/Infinity/Bernstein.shtml

Comment: Binary expansion is "almost bijective", the only problem is that there is some ambiguity about numbers which can be written as ending in infinitely many $1$s, since these can also be written as ending in infinitely many $0$s by performing an "infinite carry". "Correcting" that by choosing a "canonical" representation of these numbers (e.g. deciding that valid binary expansions never end in an infinite tail of $1$s) produces a bijection between a certain subset of $P(\mathbb{N})$ and $[0,1]$, which reduces the problem to showing that $P(\mathbb{N})$ and this subset have the same cardinality.

Comment: To prove *that*, the usual way I know to proceed is to argue that this subset of $P(\mathbb{N})$ has a countable complement, then you construct an injection from $P(\mathbb{N})$ to this subset using a Schroder-Bernstein-like argument. Then the other way has the inclusion map, so Schroder-Bernstein applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea is to consider numbers in $[0,1]$ expanded in their binary representation $a_0.a_1a_2\dots$, where $a_n\in\{0,1\}$ *and*, for any $n>0$, there exists $m>n$ with $a_m=0$ (which excludes representations that are “eventually $1$”.

Each number in $[0,1]$ has exactly one representation of this type; for $x\in[0,1]$, call $x_n$ the $n$-th digit and define
$$
f(x)=\{n\in\mathbb{N}:x_n=1\}
$$
For instance $f(1)={0}$ and $f(0)=\emptyset$, whereas $f(1/2)=\{1\}$. If $x\ne y$, then $x_n\ne y_n$ for at least one $n$, so either $n\in f(x)$ and $n\notin f(y)$ or $n\notin f(x)$ and $n\in f(y)$. In particular, $f(x)\ne f(y)$.

For the converse injection, given $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$, consider the binary alignment defined by
$$
0.a_10a_30a_50\dots
$$
where $a_{2n+1}=1$ if $n\in A$ and $a_{2n+1}=0$ if $n\notin A$.

Different sets define different numbers in $[0,1]$; the inserted zeros in even positions ensure that no alignment is “eventually $1$”.

Comment: Thanks, you led me to my solution. Check out my edited question—I thought you might be interested in my alternative solution to the converse injection that avoids the inserted zeros.

Comment: @rorty Yes, the alternative approach is good: the problem is to avoid “eventually $b-1$” sequences, where $b$ is the radix.

Answer (score 0):

For each real number, choose a decimal representation $a=0.a_1a_2\dots$ in binary, and define $f:\mathbb{R}\to P(\mathbb{N})$ by noting that since $\mathbb{N}$ is equinumerous to $\mathbb{N}\times \{0, 1\}$, we have a bijection, $h:P(\mathbb{N}\times\{0, 1\})\to P(\mathbb{N})$, so we may define $g(a)=\{(i, a_i)|i\in\mathbb{N}\}$, and letting $f=hg$ we obtain the desired injection.

Answer (score 0):

Define $f: [0, 1] \to P(\mathbb{N})$ to be $f(x) = \{ 2^i 3^{a_i} | i = 1, 2, \ldots \}$ where $a_i$ are the decimal expansion of $x = \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \frac{a_i}{10^i}$, $a_i \in \{0, 1, \ldots, 9\}$. Show that this is injection.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an injection $g:\mathbb R\to P(\mathbb Q)$ by setting $g(x)=\{q\in\mathbb Q:q\lt x\}$ (the lower Dedekind cut). Now restrict $g$ to $[0,1]$ and compose it with a bijection from $P(\mathbb Q)$ to $P(\mathbb N)$ to get your injection $f:[0,1]\to P(\mathbb N).$

For the other direction, you can get an injection $h:P(\mathbb N)\to\mathbb R$ by simply defining $$h(S)=\sum_{n\in S}10^{-n}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Your function $P(\mathbb N)\to[0,1]$ is not an injection.  For example, $\{1\}$ and $\mathbb N\setminus \{1\}$ map to $0.1$ and $0.0111\dots$, which are the same number $1/2$.

In fact, if you use the same trick in the opposite direction then you do get an injection $[0,1]\to P(\mathbb N)$, encoding a real number as a set of natural numbers using some chosen 'canonical' binary expansion for each number.  For example, given the choice, you could always choose the non-terminating binary expansion.

Therefore, the question you should be asking is: 'How do I find an injection from $P(\mathbb N)$ to $[0,1]$?'  You will probably have to do this in a slightly clumsy way.

As an idea, let $P_{\inf}(\mathbb N)$ denote the set of infinite subsets of $\mathbb N$.  These subsets correspond to non-terminating binary expansions, and this gives us an injection $P_{\inf}(\mathbb N)\to[0,1]$.  Now there is an injection $[0,1]\to[0,1]$ sending $0.a_1a_2a_3\dots$ to $0.0a_10a_20a_3\dots$.  Composing this with our injection gives us an injection $P_{\inf}(\mathbb N)\to[0,1]$ that is very far from being surjective, and now there are plenty of spare elements of $[0,1]$ that we can map the finite subsets of $P(\mathbb N)$, giving us an injection $P(\mathbb N)\to[0,1]$.

Comment: My function is an injection if I still consider only 0s and 1s but in decimal rather than binary. E.g., 0.1 and 0.011111111... would be different numbers in decimal. But you and egreg led me to the injection I'm looking for (which is to use binary but only consider canonical representations).

Comment: Very good point, and well done.  Now I think of it, your solution using decimal is much more elegant than mine.